# Passing an object to a class contructor by reference - confused about behavior

Tags: php, object, pass-by-reference

I've been working with older projects lately and upgrading them a little bit. I've constructed code similar to the one below:

```
class Foo{

    public $some_variable = "AAA";

    public function do_some_action(){

        echo $this->some_variable;
        // Prints out 'AAA'

        $bar = new Bar($this);
        $bar->different_action();

        echo $this->some_variable;
        // Prints out 'BBB' - why ?      

    }
} class Bar {

    //Constructor
    public function Bar($foo){
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function different_action(){
        $this->foo->some_variable = "BBB";
    }

}
```

I don't exactly understand why function Bar::different_action() affects Foo's public variable. Is >>$this<< always passed as reference in this situation? I would expect some kind of reference, like:

```
public function Bar(&$foo){
            $this->foo =& $foo;
}
```

My logic fails for sure, but I would appreciate if someone told me where and why :)

Comment: Objects are passed by reference.

Comment: Thank you - it may seem basic , but I didn't know that!

Comment: Accepting my answer would be very kind of you

Comment: I will do that in 8 minutes. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Objects are passed by reference:
Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: Something is only "passed by reference" if it has `&`, and passed by value otherwise. Period. "Objects" are not values in PHP5 and cannot be "passed"; rather, what you have is a pointer to an object. It is passed by value if the parameter doesn't have `&`.

Answer (score 0):

`Bar`'s constructor's parameter doesn't have a `&`, therefore it is **passed by value**. Pass by reference is only when the parameter has a `&`.

Pass by value means that the function gets a separate copy of the value, and assigning to the parameter in the called function (in this case, `$foo = something` in the constructor) does not affect the caller. However, since the value in this case is an object pointer, you can use it to call a method on the pointed-to object that changes the state of the object.

If you know C++, here is the equivalent of the code in C++, preserving the structure of the code and each line, and adding types as required in C++:

```
class Foo{
  public:
    string some_variable = "AAA";

    void do_some_action(){

        cout << this->some_variable;
        // Prints out 'AAA'

        Bar *bar = new Bar(this);
        bar->different_action();

        cout << this->some_variable;
        // Prints out 'BBB' - why ?      

    }
} class Bar {
    Foo *foo;
  public:
    //Constructor
    Bar(Foo *foo){
        this->foo = foo;
    }

    void different_action(){
        this->foo->some_variable = "BBB";
    }

}
```

In this C++ code, there is no pass by reference. (Only when a parameter has `&` is it pass by reference in C++, just like in PHP.) Can you see why the object is changed?

Passing an object pointer by reference, as you do in your last code sample, would only be useful if you wanted to assign to the parameter, thus changing the object pointer variable in the calling scope (but `$this` is not assignable anyway, so it wouldn't make sense in this case).

Comment: Thanks for your input! I don't exactly understand what do you mean by assinging a parameter. Parameter for object contructor ?

Comment: @PiWo: Parameter is the variable that a passed argument goes into, e.g. `$foo` in the constructor. If you assign to that variable, i.e. `$foo = something`, then if it's passed by value (no `&`), it has no effect on the caller; but if it's passed by reference (with `&`), then it does the same as if you assigned to the passed variable in the calling scope. Of course, pass-by-reference assumes you pass a real variable, not `$this`.

Answer (score -1):

In PHP, all objects are passed by reference. All other variables to be passed **by reference** require an ampersand (`&` - the reference operator) in front of the function/method argument.

```
function some_action(&$variable) {
   $variable = 'new value';
}

$variable = 'string';

some_action($variable); // $variable now has a new value. Passing objects to this function will always pass them by reference - automatically.
```

Comment: Wrong. Something is always passed by value if the parameter doesn't have `&`, regardless of type; and always passed by value if there is `&`. "Objects" are not values and cannot be "passed". Passing an object pointer (or any other type) by reference allows you to assign to the parameter as if you assigned to in passed variable, which you cannot do if passed by value.

Comment: Not true,in practice, objects are always passed by reference. The majority of developers don't care about how this is taken care on a low-level scale. The down voting was unnecessary.

Comment: It is very true. When there is no `&`, passing and assigning works exactly the same in PHP as in Java. According to your logic, "objects are always passed by reference" in Java. But look around anywhere and you will see that Java has only pass by value.